# Converting from JBoss AS7 to Wildfly

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly-10

My project references the following Jar's and I am wondering whether these are the correct Jars for my version of WWildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final).

- jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
- jboss-ejb3-ext-api-2.2.0.Final.jar
- jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
- jboss-jsp-api_2.3_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar

Are these needed for Wildfly or are these the correct ones for WWildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These version of jar will work with WildFly-10 release without any issue.